# Installed sqlite3 but still getting error couldn't find database client: sqlite3. Check your $PATH and try again.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am new to rails. I have installed sqlite3, but still i'm getting the below error when i try to start dbconsole from the root of application folder.

"Couldn't find database client: sqlite3. Check your $PATH and try again."

When i check for sqlite3 using cmd "bundle show sqlite3", it shows the path as "/home/railsuser/projects/rails1/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8".

Please help me in fixing this issue. I am struggling since 3 days and no luck.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it to your path?  try export PATH=$PATH:`bundle show sqlite3`  see where the actual sqlite executable is under the sqlite3-1.3.8 directory, use find `bundle show sqlite3` -name sqlite3 -print
and add that to the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I exported path as below and tried ./bin/rails/dbconsole. Still the issue is not resolved.  export PATH=$PATH:/home/railsuser/projects/rails1/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3

Comment: does which sqlite3 show anything in the shell?  how are you starting dbconsole?

Comment: which sqlite3 -- doesn't return any output. I tried to startiu sing "./bin/rails dbconsole" and "bundle exec rails db".

Comment: if which sqlite3 doesn't show anything, then your PATH is wrong.  do ls -l /home/railsuser/projects/rails1/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3‌​-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3  if that's the actual executable, remove the /sqlite3 from the path.

Comment: ls -l have listed the below files in the directory "backup.c
backup.h
backup.o
database.c
database.h
database.o
exception.c
exception.h
exception.o
extconf.rb
Makefile
mkmf.log
sqlite3.c
sqlite3_native.so
sqlite3.o
sqlite3_ruby.h
statement.c
statement.h
statement.o.

Comment: after changing the $PATH to sqlite3-1.3/ext/, the error msg changed  to /home/railsuser/projects/rails1/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands/dbconsole.rb:100:in `exec': Permission denied - /home/railsuser/projects/rails1/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3 (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: first we need to find where your sqlite3 executable is located, the directory contents you pasted do not have the executable.  Find out where the executable is, then invoke it to make sure it is the correct one, then add it's containing directory to your PATH.  Usually the executable is in a path that ends with bin/